# After installing MPLAB X qemu started reporting undefined symbol: libusb_get_device_speed and unknown OS type hvm

Tags: pic, qemu, microchip, libusb-1.0

After installing MPLAB X some programs started reporting `undefined symbol:  libusb_get_device_speed`. Qemu example:

```
2014-06-02 12:41:50.059+0000: 1963: error : virCommandWait:2348 : internal error: Child process (LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin /usr/bin/qemu-system-xtensaeb -help) unexpected exit status 127: /usr/bin/qemu-system-xtensaeb: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/qemu-system-xtensaeb: undefined symbol: libusb_get_device_speed

2014-06-02 12:41:50.075+0000: 1963: error : virDomainDefParseXML:11543 : unknown OS type hvm
```

What happened? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [microchip forum](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m729021.aspx):
The installer created symbolic links to an older version of libusb. If your /usr/local/lib has the following symbolic links:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/lib
libmchpusb-1.0.so -> /opt/microchip/mplabcomm1.0/libusb-1.0.so.0.0.0*
libusb-1.0.so -> libmchpusb-1.0.so
```

then:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so
```

If you don't have the links then check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/488915/error-unknown-os-type-hvm-help-deploying-vm-opennebula).